# Azure AD B2C, unauthorized_client Error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured the Azure AD B2C application, but when I run the application getting the subject mentioned error, what could be the reason.

> Error.
>
> > An error occurred while processing your request.
> >
> > > "unauthorized_client"

Is it a problem with Azure AD B2C configuration ? or problem with Code ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem, while configure the Azure B2C application, by mistake set the allow implicit flow to 'No', it suppose to be 'Yes', so I was getting the error, unauthorized client error.